# Displaying a shadow that follows the inline box around text content closely

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve an effect where I have a shadow that follows text content closely.

I've documented my progress here: https://codepen.io/wolfr/pen/QEGOdY?editors=1100

`text-shadow` doesn't fit my needs. It produces an inferior shadow (test: https://codepen.io/wolfr/pen/KMNyXj?editors=1100 )

The problem with my current approach is that it's pretty bad for people using screen readers.

I've tried several methods to hide HTML content from being read by sceen readers in another pen [here](https://codepen.io/wolfr/pen/yJVPVd). They include using media queries and the `speak: none` attribute. None of them work. I can't position the box off-screen (the classic method) since I actually needs its layout. I've also tried hiding content in a `:before attribute` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You want make a shadow that follows close the text around? If do, you can use multiple text-shadow in order to make a more elaborated shadow.

```css
p {
  color: #d53400;
  font-size: 32pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 8px #555, -2px 0 0 #555, 0 2px 0 #555, 0 -2px 0 #555, 1px 1px #555, -1px -1px 0 #555, 1px -1px 4px #555, -1px 1px 0 #555;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Text shadow<br />This is another line</p>
```